# How to get notified of new automatically archived emails in Gmail?

Tags: notifications, gmail

I am a very organized person, and thus also in the case of my emails. I have taken the time to set various filters and labels to keep my emails organized, some of these filters automatically archive messages, i.e. labels are applied to emails, and they get archived (hence these messages skip the inbox).

[image: Setting a filter to auto-archive messages in Gmail webpage]

These days I am receiving some emails that belong to a specific label, about topics in which I'm working currently, but since they are not reaching the inbox, my smartphone does not notify me when they arrive. However, when I expand the list of recent labels, I find that there are unread messages in the label in which I am interested.

[image: No new messages in my inbox] [image: New message count for specific label]

When I open the folder (label), I find the new unread email message.

[image: This is the new auto-archived message]

What do I have to configure in order to get notified of these automatically archived emails in Gmail?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The steps you have to take are the following ones:

1. Expand the list of recent labels, but this time tap the option **Show all labels**.
   [image: Show all labels]
2. This will take you to the list of all your labels, in whose bottom you'll see the option **Manage labels**: tap there.
   [image: Labels list]
3. In the list of labels, tap the one you want to be notified about. 
   [image: Manage labels]
4. By default that label has *Label sync and notify* disabled. Tap the option **Sync messages**
   [image: Label sync and notify disabled]
5. It will open a popup dialog with sync options. Choose and tap one **different** to *Sync: None*.
   [image: Sync options]
6. The above will enable the notifications, now you can choose its options according the way you want to be notified.
   [image: Enabling sync and notify]
7. Exit the label options for changes to be applied. From now on, you'll receive notifications about unread messages for that label too (in Jelly Bean, you'll see the extended notification, as with inbox emails). You'll be able to open the email message tapping on that notification.
   [image: New notification] [image: Extended notification in Jelly Bean]
   [image: New message, still archived]

Comment: I tried all the above that you mentioned but the problem is that the sync label is information is not retained after sometime. Regards,
Muneer.